# how to clear a specific header in libcurl

Tags: curl, http-headers, libcurl, libcurl.net

```
CURL *handle;
struct curl_slist *slist=NULL;
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "X-libcurl: coolness");
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Authorization: Bearer retrffhj");

curl_slist_free_all(slist); /* clears all header list */
```

How can I clear the header with key Authorization and rest header information should be retained as it is.

Answer (score 0):

1. clear the entire list
2. make a new list with the header(s) you want in it
3. use the new list

Comment: I tried that,  after clearing the entire list and preparing new list, which gives me Bad Request response.

Comment: that could be a totally separate issue though, show us your code and we might spot something - or not

Answer (score 0):

```
list = curl_slist_append(list, "Accept:");
```

If you add a header with no content as in 'Accept:' (no data on the right side of the colon), the internally used header will get disabled.

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html